# Excel: How to match a string and find all row data?

Tags: vba, excel, csv, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets, `A` and `B`.

`A` includes rows with a given `slug`, and a few 'metrics' columns.

```
Slug | Views | Shares
aaa  | 10    | 5
bbb  | 25    | 2
ccc  | 5     | 0
```

Sheet `B` has a huge list of `slugs` (some which might not be contained in sheet `A`).

I basically want to "search" sheet `A` by `slug` value, and "fill in" those corresponding values.

Here's a sample output of sheet `B`:

```
Slug | Views | Shares
xxx  | -     | -
bbb  | 25    | 2
aaa  | 10    | 5
ddd  | -     | -
eee  | -     | -
```

I will eventually perform some math on them when moving them over, but this is the start I need before I can do that.

Comment: VLOOKUP is what you want

Comment: ^^ plus perhaps an `IFERROR` wrapping it (i.e. `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(....),"-")`) to handle the cases which don't exist on sheet A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use VLOOKUP.

For example to get the 25 in bbb in sheet B, the formula would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A!$A$2:$C$4,2,FALSE)
```

The first argument A2 is bbb in sheet B, the second argument is the table in sheet A, the third argument says to return column 2 (the Views column), and the final argument indicates exact match.

Comment: You are a god among sheet slinging office mortals